# Get page photo likes from facebook open graph

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Using PHP, i can retrieve the images from a facebook page using a URL like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/albumid/photos?access_token=XXXXXXX&debug=all&fields=images&format=json&method=get&pretty=1&suppress_http_code=1
```

But how can i get the likes count for each photos ? The URL above only returns image url, width and height. I'm looking for the number of likes for each page photos (not user photos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how can i get the likes count for each photos ?

By requesting the relevant field, same as you are already doing with `images`:

```
/albumd-id/photos?fields=images,likes
```

That will give you the individual likes. Since you are not interested in those, but only the total count, add summary=1 and a limit of 0, which using field expansion syntax would look like this:

```
/albumd-id/photos?fields=images,likes.summary(1).limit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

From you API you will get photo ID of each photo you have to use that Photo ID .

TRY this ,

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{photo-id}/likes'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

**OR**

```
GET /v2.8/{photo-id}/likes HTTP/1.1
```

[For more information check this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/likes/)